# Save decimal and thousands separator in Excel document

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf

Is it possible to save/embed decimal and thousands separator in Excel document. The problem is that if Excel document moved to another computer with different locale the decimal and thousands separator adjusted accordingly. I would like to preserve separator and save it to document. Many would ask why I need that, the answer that we have PDF Server hosted on USA Server with US Locale and it change separator.

Comment: You could save the numbers as text but this will restrict other uses of your data.

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose That's not a solution because it requires additional work to adjust every document which is send for conversion.

Comment: The way Excel handles functions and locales is a pain. It uses translated function names and locales on the creator's machine and then it'll become a mess when transferring to other PCs

Comment: @Tomas Excel just saves the numeric values in the cell. The separators are applied by the OS of the computer, and any formatting depends on the cell formats within Excel. If you describe more clearly the nature of your problem, an appropriate solution might be suggested.

Answer (score 0):

According to all my knowledge and after really long search, it is *not* possible to store the decimal and thousand separator on a per file basis in Microsoft Excel.

This has been asked and requested from Microsoft for YEARS (as you can see e.g. [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other/change-the-decimal-point-to-a-comma/5f7fa663-cded-4d9d-9c91-4d744daa91fa)) without any solution. I think that the Americans simply cannot imagine the multinational environment in other parts of the world - like living in Czech Republic, working for a Finnish company (hence having a Finnish IP address when working on VPN) and creating documents in Swedish.